# Continuity of the function with composition

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I make the exercise in my book of analysis and I have a problem or maybe not:)) with understanding of this example.

Let $g$ be defined on $\mathbb R$ by $g(1):=0$ and $g(x):=2 ,x \neq 1$ and let $f(x):=1+x \quad \forall x \in \mathbb R$. Show that $\lim_{x \to 0} g \circ f \neq (g \circ f)(0)$. The question is, why is it not true?

$\textbf{My argument}$: $(g \circ f)(0)=g(f(0))=g(0+1)=g(1)=0$, but

$\lim_{x\to 0}g \circ f=\lim_{x \to \infty} (g \circ f)(\frac{1}{x})=\lim_{x\to \infty} g(f(\frac{1}{x}))=\lim_{x\to\infty} g(1+\frac{1}{x})=2.$

Is my argument correct?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

You could just say that $(g \circ f)(0) = 1$, whereas:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to 0} g \circ f (x) = \lim_{x \to 0} g(f(x)) = \lim_{x \to 0} g(1+x) \stackrel{\text{u = x+1}}{=} \lim_{u \to 1} g(u) = 2.
\end{equation}

**Another way** to do this would be:
\begin{equation}
(g\circ f )(x) = g(f(x))=g(1+x)= 
\begin{cases}
   0,& x=0\\
    2,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
It's clear that $\lim_{x \to 0} (g\circ f)(x) \neq (g\circ f)(0)$.

Comment: thank you! But do you think my argument is correct?

Comment: You're welcome! No, I don't see any problem with that, except that you are torturing yourself. :)